# Required input in form mat-chip-list in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-material

I create a basic form with angular 6. There are some inputs and I use "required" in order to display an error message and disabled the submit button.

Here it is:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" #myForm="ngForm">
  <div id="iterationField" class="col-sm-5">
    <h6>Iterations to calculate performance</h6>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput type="number" id="iter" required [(ngModel)]="iteration" name="iter" #iter="ngModel" min="1">
    </mat-form-field>
    <div *ngIf="iter.invalid && (iter.dirty || iter.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
      Iteration is required
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" color="primary" [disabled]="!myForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This works properly.
Now what I am trying to do is to add the angular material chip-list. Following the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview) and the [example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xenrkmnaorp?file=app%2Fchips-input-example.ts) I have this:

```
        <div id="costField">
          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <mat-chip-list #chipCostList>
              <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of svr.cost" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(item, 'cost')">
                {{item}}
                <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
              </mat-chip>
              <input placeholder="Cost" [matChipInputFor]="chipCostList" [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
                (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event, 'cost')" [(ngModel)]="costValue" #cost="ngModel" name="cost" required>
            </mat-chip-list>
          </mat-form-field>
          <div *ngIf="cost.invalid && (cost.dirty || cost.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
            Cost is required
          </div>
        </div>
```

However, this doesn't work. I have no error message.
I tried to add required in the mat-chip-list element but it doesn't work neither.
I reproduced a similar example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bwxzxh-gk8j67?file=app/chips-input-example.html).

The chips and the input are not linked. I mean the input doesn't recognise the chips. So if you just click on the fruit input and then click next to it. The error message will appear whereas there are some chips already inside.

How can I make it work ?

Comment: The structure looks a bit weird. Why is the MatList inside a MatFormField and why is there an input in MatList?

Comment: This is how it's built in the angular documentation (links in the post)

Comment: I tried your code, and it worked. You should show more detail about Component file and full template

Comment: I reproduced an easier example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bwxzxh-gk8j67?file=app/chips-input-example.html) . The chips and the input are not linked. I mean the input doesn't recognise the chips. So if you just click on the fruit input and then click next to it. The error message will appear whereas there are some chips already inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old, but I came across it while facing this issue myself, so figured I'd share the solution that I found as well.

When using `mat-chip-list` (or `mat-chip-grid` in newer Angular) with `input`, the `required` has to go on the `mat-chip-list` instead of the `input`. So for your code:

```html
<div id="costField">
  <mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <mat-chip-list #chipCostList required> <!-- <---------- -->
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of svr.cost" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(item, 'cost')">
        {{item}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>
      <input placeholder="Cost" [matChipInputFor]="chipCostList" [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
        (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event, 'cost')" [(ngModel)]="costValue" #cost="ngModel" name="cost">
    </mat-chip-list>
  </mat-form-field>
  <div *ngIf="cost.invalid && (cost.dirty || cost.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    Cost is required
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are using the chip list input inside a form group, the form control will also go on the `mat-chip-list`/`mat-chip-grid` element, and in the callback you give to `matChipInputTokenEnd` you need to set the form control value e.g.

```html
<div id="costField">
  <mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <mat-chip-list #chipCostList required [formControl]="formGroup.controls['cost']>
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of svr.cost" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(item, 'cost')">
        {{item}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>
      <input placeholder="Cost" [matChipInputFor]="chipCostList" [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
        (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event, 'cost')" [(ngModel)]="costValue" #cost="ngModel" name="cost">
    </mat-chip-list>
  </mat-form-field>
  <div *ngIf="cost.invalid && (cost.dirty || cost.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    Cost is required
  </div>
</div>
```

```
add(event: MatChipInputEvent, name: string): void {
  ...
  this.formGroup.controls['cost'].setValue(event.option.value);
}
```

(If you don't set the value of the form control in the callback, the form sees the input as invalid even when you select something).

Where I got the answer: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10992